# Redirect htaccess does not work correctly with my new wordpress site

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have an old website that works fine (`www.example.com`). I have created a new website (`www.example.com/wordpress`) and I thought I could use `.htaccess` to redirect as I've done it for other html websites in the past.

I get the result: `www.example.com/worpress/wordpress/wordpress.........` until it's in error.

Can someone help me?

I used this command in `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/wordpress/
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/wordpress/
> ```

You can't use a mod_alias `Redirect` directive in this way to redirect to a subdirectory *on the same site* because the `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching and everything after the match is appended to the target (which is how this directive is able to redirect all URL-paths to the same URL-path at the target). So the above naturally redirects like so:

- `http://example.com/` - Initial request
- `http://example.com/wordpress/` - First redirect
- `http://example.com/wordpress/wordpress/` - Second redirect, because the directive matches `/` and everything after the match (ie. `wordpress/`) is appended to the end of the target (ie. `http://www.mysite.fr/wordpress/`) to become `http://www.mysite.fr/wordpress/` + `wordpress/`.
- etc.

Which is a "redirect loop".

Try the following instead...

Assuming the WordPress `.htaccess` is located at `/wordpress/.htaccess` (ie. in the `/wordpress`) subdirectory, then you could perform this redirect using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file (at `/.htaccess`) instead. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ /wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This directive states that if the URL-path does not already start `/wordpress/` (the slash prefix is omitted in `.htaccess`) then prefix `/wordpress` to the requested URL-path. (The `REQUEST_URI` server variable already contains a slash prefix.)

This assumes you don't need to access your old website in the document root. If you do then you will need additional *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives).

Only change the above 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) - if this is intended to be a permanent change - after you have tested to make sure it is working OK.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as any erroneous 301s are likely to have been cached by the browser.

---

**UPDATE:** (From comments...)

> I have tried your suggestion as to the `.htaccess` file at the root of the old site with this content :
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule !^wordpress/ /wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
> Redirect permanent / http://www.mysite.fr/wordpress/
> ```
>
> and I get the answer : ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS The redirect loop is still not solved. Do you have any idea how I could solve this?

You need to remove the `Redirect` directive. So, it should simply read:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ /wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

And make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question.
The .htaccess file was a the root of the old site, what needs to be changed then ?

Comment: As mentioned above, add the two directives stated: `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteRule` to the root `.htaccess` file (of the old site). If you have any existing directives in that file then they should probably be removed.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion as to the .htaccess file at the root of the old site with this content :

Comment: I have tried your suggestion as to the .htaccess file at the root of the old site with this content : 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ /wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
Redirect permanent / http://www.mysite.fr/wordpress/         

and I get the answer : ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
The redirect loop is still not solved.
Do you have any idea how I could solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the existing `Redirect` directive (that is what's causing the "redirect loop" - as stated in your question and explained in my answer). The directive(s) I posted above are to be used _instead of_ the directive you posted. You must also make sure that the browser cache (and possibly any intermediary caches) are cleared before testing (because 301 redirects - including those made in error - are cached _hard_ by the browser).

Comment: I am sorry but could you be more specific, I cannot figure out how to correct it...
Sorry to be so green ;-)

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried using only :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ /wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
and I still get looping redirection. I did flush the navigator's cache to no effect.
Have you got a clue ?
Many thanks

Comment: I did what you suggested in your correction and for some reason I had to exit the ftp and reconnect to reload the page. It now works !!!
Many Many thanks MrWhite :D !!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working in the end! If you can mark the answer as "accepted" (checkmark on the left, below the up/down voting arrows) that would be much appreciated, thanks. :) Once you have 15+rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful.